# PHP mPDF Certificate Printing with Customer Name and Points

Tags: php, pdf-generation, mpdf

I have to generate PDF Certificate file with background image - A4 size as the fix format Certificate file and dynamic run time `Participant Name` and `Winning Points`, mentioned in the Generated PDF using `mPDF`.

Now the issue is, my certificate to generate with PDF is landscape and text should be placed accordingly onto that.

I tried with `html / css - text transform 90 degree method`, but that is not support with PDF generation code.

Certificate file: http://goo.gl/kV576i

Any quick tricks for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, it was all about understanding mPDF structure and page addition method as below:

```
    include("../mpdf.php");

    $mpdf = new mPDF('c','A4','','',42,15,67,67,20,15);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->AddPage('L','','','','',25,25,55,45,18,12);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output('mpdf.pdf','I');
    exit;
```

Here is the complete code with CSS and other settings, just in case if useful for someone:

```
    <?php

    $html = '
    <style style="text/css">
    body {
      background-image: url("background-image.jpg");
      background-image-resize: 6; // mpdf style class
    }
    .centrar{
        position: absolute;
        border: 0px solid red;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0 auto;
        top: 40%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2em;
        font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue Light, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .points{
        position: absolute;
        border: 0px solid green;
        width: 63.5%;
        left: 0 auto;
        top: 64.7%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue Light, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    <p class="centrar">'. ucwords('some name here') .'</p>
    <p class="centrar points">30</p>
    ';

    //==============================================================
    //==============================================================
    //==============================================================

    include("../mpdf.php");

    $mpdf = new mPDF('c','A4','','',42,15,67,67,20,15);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->AddPage('L','','','','',25,25,55,45,18,12);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output('mpdf.pdf','I');
    exit;

    //==============================================================
    //==============================================================
    //==============================================================

    ?>
```

Good Luck !